# Solution of Dirichlet problem and the minimization of energy

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation, greens-theorem

[image]

[image]

[image]

Could someone explain why can we have $\frac{\partial}{\partial c_k}E(w)=0?$

Why the author can derive respect to constants $c_k$?

Also I don't understand the rest of the solution, it's supposed to use green first identity: $$\int\int_A v\nabla u\cdot \overrightarrow n dA=\int\int\int_V\nabla v\nabla udV+\int\int\int_Vv\nabla^2u dV$$ but I don't know how.

please help

Comment: It’s just finding the minimum of a function by setting the gradient to zero.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Could you elaborate please, I don't get the idea, which gradient?

Comment: The energy is a function of $c_1,\ldots c_k.$ That is the function you need to minimize. So take its gradient and set it equal to zero, like you do to find (local) extrema of any function.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen oh I see, but why the summatory vanish, i.e. how do you pass from here $(\nabla w_0,\sum c_j\nabla w_j)$ to $(\nabla w_0,\nabla w_k)$ ?

Comment: Don't think I understand you. But the second think you wrote down is the partial derivative of the first thing with respect to $c_k.$